# ExpressJS and passport-linkedin-oauth2 cannot authenticate

Tags: node.js, oauth, linkedin-api, passport.js

I wastrying to make a simple example of using passport-linkedin-oauth2 then faced this problem:

This is the log on the server side:

```
{ [CastError: Cast to number failed for value "XXXXXX" at path "oauthID"]
message: 'Cast to number failed for value "XXXXXX" at path "oauthID"',
name: 'CastError',
type: 'number',
value: 'XXXXXX',
path: 'oauthID' }
```

And this is the error log on client-side:

```
TokenError: missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/Users/percevio/projects/web-learning/passportjs/open-auth/node_modules/passport-linkedin-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:298:12)
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/Users/percevio/projects/web-learning/passportjs/open-auth/node_modules/passport-linkedin-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:345:16)
at /Users/percevio/projects/web-learning/passportjs/open-auth/node_modules/passport-linkedin-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:171:43
at /Users/percevio/projects/web-learning/passportjs/open-auth/node_modules/passport-linkedin-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18
at passBackControl (/Users/percevio/projects/web-learning/passportjs/open-auth/node_modules/passport-linkedin-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:124:9)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/percevio/projects/web-learning/passportjs/open-auth/node_modules/passport-linkedin-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:944:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

I am using ExpressJS, mongoose and have registered the Linkedin app to get API key and secret key. And I already check the OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs.

The User schema:

```
//Create a user model
var User = mongoose.model('User',{
    oauthID:Number,
    name:String,
    created:Date
});
```

And this is how I configured linkedStrategy:

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    clientID:config.linkedin_oauth2.clientID,
    clientSecret:config.linkedin_oauth2.clientSecret,
    callbackURL:'http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback',
    state:true,
    scope: ['r_basicprofile']
},
```

Any suggestion? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found an answer. I ran into the same issue, and it turned out that upgrading from node 0.10.35 to 0.12.2 fixes it for me.